# Override gate-check in Azure Release Pipeline (YAML)

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=azure-devops,

we control our release deployment via multiple gates.

One of the gate-check is very flaky and we want to grant permission to our on-call engineer to override this specific gate if they manually verify things are working good.

How do we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You always should have the option to ignore specific gates:

[image: ignore gate]
[image: ignored gate]
[image: release continued]